# Rotate Text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone suggest a way of rotating text by any angle without using something like Flash or Silverlight. I'd like to use a slanted image with the text following the same angle.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit late, but I have written some code to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/73DzT/139/

```
Object.prototype.rotate = function(d) {
    var s = "rotate(" + d + "deg)";
    if (this.style) { // regular DOM Object
        this.style.MozTransform = s
        this.style.WebkitTransform = s;
        this.style.OTransform = s;
        this.style.MSTransform = s;
        this.style.transform = s;
    } else if (this.css) { // JQuery Object
        this.css("-moz-transform", s);
        this.css("-webkit-transform", s);
        this.css("-o-transform", s);
        this.css("-ms-transform", s);
        this.css("transform", s);
    }
    this.setAttribute("rotation", d);
}
```

can be used with regular objects or with JQuery objects. and stores an attribute called "rotation" to give you it's current rotation value.

Comment: That almost works. :-)
You need to add a{ display: block } to the css.  Otherwise, the link does not rotate.  Cool, simple solution though!

Answer (score 0):

You can try css rotation too http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

Comment: This only works in increments of 90deg :( The poster and I are looking for arbitrary degrees/radians...

Answer (score 0):

Found this jQuery library [jQueryRotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) which has worked great for me.  Notice that it's not the same library that poke linked to even though the name is very similar.

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: This technique is well documented on the Internet. It only works in increments of 90deg :( The poster and I are looking for arbitrary degrees/radians...